# Barrier operations in NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, barrier

How can we implement `dispatch_barrier_async`'s equivalent behavior using `NSOperationQueue` or any user-defined data-structure based on `NSOperationQueue`?

The requirement is, whenever a *barrier operation* is submitted it should wait until all *non-barrier operations* submitted earlier finish their execution and blocks other operations submitted after that.

- Non-barrier operations should be able to perform concurrently.
- Barrier operations should execute serially.

NB: Not using **GCD**,as it doesn't provide(or atleast difficult) much access over the operations, like cancelling single operation, etc.

Comment: You also can't cancel NSOperation if it's already running.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I don’t intend to cancel any running NSOperation and neither the dispatch_barrier_async does that. The barrier function will wait for the previous operations to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more or less what [jeffamaphone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74815/jeffamaphone) was saying, but I put up a [gist](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/9648377) that should, in rough outline, do what you ask.

I create a `NSMutableArray` of `NSOperationQueue`s, which serves as a "queue of queues". Every time you add a `BarrierOperation` object, you tack a fresh *suspended* op queue on the end. That becomes the `addingQueue`, to which you add subsequent operations.

```
- (void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)op {
    @synchronized (self) {
        if ([op isKindOfClass:[BarrierOperation class]]) {
            [self addBarrierOperation:(id)op];
        } else {
            [[self addingQueue] addOperation:op];
        }
    }
}

// call only from @synchronized block in -addOperation:
- (void)addBarrierOperation:(BarrierOperation *)barrierOp {
    [[self addingQueue] setSuspended:YES];

    for (NSOperation *op in [[self addingQueue] operations]) {
        [barrierOp addDependency:op];
    }

    [[self addingQueue] addOperation:barrierOp];

    // if you are free to set barrierOp.completionBlock, you could skip popCallback and do that

    __block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    NSOperation *popCallback = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [weakSelf popQueue];
    }];
    [popCallback addDependency:barrierOp];
    [[self addingQueue] addOperation:popCallback];
    [[self addingQueue] setSuspended:NO];

    NSOperationQueue *opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [opQueue setSuspended:YES];

    [_queueOfQueues addObject:opQueue]; // fresh empty queue to add to
}
```

When one `NSOperationQueue` finishes, it gets popped and the next one starts running.

```
- (void)popQueue
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSAssert([_queueOfQueues count], @"should always be one to pop");
        [_queueOfQueues removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        if ([_queueOfQueues count]) {
            // first queue is always running, all others suspended
            [(NSOperationQueue *)_queueOfQueues[0] setSuspended:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

I might have missed something crucial. The devil's in the details.

This smells a bit like a homework assignment to me. If so, tell me what grade I get. :)

---

Addendum: Via [abhilash1912](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1573221/abhilash1912)'s comment, a different but similar [approach](https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBarrierOperationQueue). That code is *tested*, so it already wins. But it is a bit stale (2 years or so as of today; some deprecated method usage). Moreover, I question whether inheriting from `NSOperationQueue` is the best path, though it has the virtue of retaining familiarity. Regardless, if you've read this far, it's probably worth looking over.

If you create or find the world's greatest BarrierQueue class, please let us know in the comments or otherwise, so it can be linked up.

Comment: No, it wasn’t an assignment, so grades for you. :P. 
It was part of my company project’s requirement where I wanted to replace GCD with NSOperationQueue to get some more flexibility and manageability.
Well, I had the idea to implement it using dependencies, but I just wanted to be sure that it’s the best possible way and needed a cleaner solution which indeed your answer provided. :)

Comment: Oh wait, I get it.  Withdrawn.

Comment: Btw, here I found some more alternatives. Daniel's comments on [this](https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBarrierOperationQueue/issues/1) seems pretty useful in this context.

Answer (score 5):

Create an `NSOperation` that is your barrier, then [use](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/addDependency%3a):

```
- (void)addDependency:(NSOperation *)operation
```

To make that barrier operation dependent on all the ones you want to come before it.

Comment: That will fulfil half of my requirements only. But kinda got the idea. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to create an `NSOperation` object that's gives you the same sort of functionality, barriers have more to do with the way the queue operates.

The main difference between using a barrier and the dependency mechanism of NSOperations is, in the case of a barrier, the thread queue waits until *all* running concurrent operations have completed, and then it runs your barrier block, while making sure that any new blocks submitted and any blocks waiting *do not run* until the critical block has passed.

With an `NSOperationQueue`, it's impossible to set up the queue in such a way that it'll enforce a proper barrier:  all `NSOperation`s added to the queue before your critical `NSOperation` must be explicitly registered as a dependency with the critical job, and once the critical job has started, you must explicitly guard the `NSOperationQueue` to make sure no other clients push jobs onto it before the critical job has finished; you guard the queue by adding the critical job as a dependency for the subsequent operations.

(In the case where you know there's only one critical job at a time, this sounds sorta easy, but there will probably be `n` critical jobs waiting at any one time, which means keeping track of the order jobs are submitted, managing the relative dependency of critical jobs relative to their dependent jobs -- some critical jobs can wait for others, some must be executed in a particular order relative to others... yikes.)

It might be possible to get this level of functionality by setting up an `NSOperationQueue` with a concurrent job max of one, but that sorta defeats the purpose of doing this, I think.  You might also be able to make this work by wrapping an `NSOperationQueue` in a facade object that protects `NSOperations` that are submitted "critically."

Comment: This is more or less what I was thinking, but Clay's answer in more explanatory. And of course it can’t implement exactly what GCD does with barrier operation. Thanks for the nice explanation anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way... don't hurt me.

Todo: save origin completion and self.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 sets queue to serial on adding. But should before execution.

```
#import "NSOperationQueue+BarrierOperation.h"

@implementation NSOperationQueue (BarrierOperation)

- (void)addOperationAsBarrier:(NSOperation *)op
{
    //TODO: needs to save origin completion
    //    if (op.completionBlock)
    //    {
    //        originBlock = op.completionBlock;
    //    }

    NSOperationQueue* qInternal = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInteger oldMaxConcurrentOperationCount = self.maxConcurrentOperationCount;

    op.completionBlock = ^{
        self.maxConcurrentOperationCount = oldMaxConcurrentOperationCount;
        NSLog(@"addOperationAsBarrier maxConcurrentOperationCount restored");
    };

    [self addOperationWithBlock:^{
        self.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        NSLog(@"addOperationAsBarrier maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1");
    }];

    [qInternal addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished...");
        [self waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    }];

    NSLog(@"added OperationAsBarrier");
    [self addOperation:op];
}

@end
```